# How can I get the innerText of the element that called the function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, printing, console

How can I get the innerText of the element that called the function?
e.g

```
<html>
<div class="item1">
          <button onclick="buttonText()" id="equalSign" type="button" name="button">Print me</button>
        </div>
</html>
```

I will like to print "Print me" in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
<script>
function buttonText(x){
    console.log(x.innerText);
}
</script>

<html>
<div class="item1">
          <button onclick="buttonText(this)" id="equalSign" type="button" name="button">Print me</button>
        </div>
</html>
```